# getting TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON error

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, http, axios

Hello I am trying to make an axios post request to an api. I am sending the api an object with two list items: Candidates and Items. Both of these items are again objects with lists inside.

Here I have the code that sends the request:

```
algoController.calculate = async (req, res) => {
  const config = {
    headers:{
      "api-key": process.env.PERSONAL_API_KEY,
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
  };
  console.log(req.body.data);
  console.log(config);
  res.send( await axios.post(process.env.API_ADDRESS, req.body.data, config)).data
};
```

here is the logged values of req.body.data which is where my inputs are:

```
{
  Candidates: [ { Width: 5000, Length: 5000, Height: 5000, MaxWeight: 1000000 } ],
  Items: [
    {
      Width: 20,
      Length: 16,
      Height: 10,
      Weight: 0,
      TagOrColor: '#00be00',
      Quantity: 10
    }
  ]
}
```

as a result I get this error:

```
 C:\Users\tlege\OneDrive\Masaüstü\bindrake\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1150
    : JSON.stringify(value);
           ^

TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    --> starting at object with constructor 'ClientRequest'
    |     property 'socket' -> object with constructor 'TLSSocket'
    --- property '_httpMessage' closes the circle
    at JSON.stringify (<anonymous>)
    at stringify (C:\Users\tlege\OneDrive\Masaüstü\bindrake\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1150:12)
    at ServerResponse.json (C:\Users\tlege\OneDrive\Masaüstü\bindrake\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:271:14)
    at ServerResponse.send (C:\Users\tlege\OneDrive\Masaüstü\bindrake\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:162:21)
    at algoController.calculate (C:\Users\tlege\OneDrive\Masaüstü\bindrake\controllers\algoController.js:14:7)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
```

Comment: i guess your mistake is by doing : res.send().data data is undefined on res.send()

Comment: ohh yes, my mistake that syntax is not good. Thank you for pointing out @Valentine!